# Excel: How to wrap cell contents in double-quotes? (SOLVED)

Tags: excel

Have an Excel sheet where many cells contain "," and other potential separator characters used in CSV files within text, in various cells. Currently all of these cells  I need to put enclosing double-quotes around such text (i.e. entire text in the cell). Wondering how should I formulate the search-replace pattern, to achieve this.

I have already tried to first do this "" addition before/after strings containing the potential separator characters, first in a text file, and then tried to copy them into the Excel sheet, but when copying this data, Excel seems to be removing/ignoring the enclosing "s.

***Edit***:
*Realised that Excel itself adds surrounding ""s around text from a cell, where it contains a comma, when generating CSV, so the comma in the text doesn't risk being mistaken for a separator.*

Comment: I work with Excel, not a lot, but to be able to help, but I'm having trouble following your question, can you give some examples can you give a few rows with examples

Comment: What makes you think you need to put enclosing double quotes around the text?  What problem do you have with the file if you do not?

Comment: Thank you for your comments JavierRivas and RonRosenfeld. Edited the question. Looks like Excel is taking care of the problem I thought might be there, but really wasn't.